# C# How do I create an array/matrix that stores the data?

Tags: c#, arrays

My file looks like this:
hello,1,2,up
goodbye,0,4,down
...

I have WordToFind which will have the first word from my file, but I want it to have both the words 'hello' and 'goodbye'.
Same for X1Coordinate, I want it to have '1' and '0', but as integers.
So how can I modify my code to do that?
I'm a beginner and I tryed to figure it out for over 3 hours and still didn't manage, so I'm sorry if it's a really basic question.

```
for (int m = 0; m < Words; m++)
{
    string LinesInFile = reader.ReadLine();

    string[] WordsWithSpecifics = LinesInFile.Split(',');
    string WordToFind = WordsWithSpecifics[0];
    int X1Coordinate = int.Parse(WordsWithSpecifics[1]);
    int Y1Coordinate = int.Parse(WordsWithSpecifics[2]);
    string WordDirection = WordsWithSpecifics[3];
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post some actual code of what you have tried and tell us what you need done. Roughly speaking you need an `object[]` to handle these kind of non homogeneous array of data.

Comment: We haven't learned objects yet. So here I read in a File line by line. And in every line I have "a word, a first number, a second number, a direction". I want to store in WordToFind all my words, in X1Coordinate all my firstnumbers, in Y1Coordinate all my second numbers and in WordDirection all the directions.

Comment: Is the data in the file always in the same format i.e. string,int,int,string...int,int? Also do you want to treat up and goodbye as separate words or just one string "up goodbye"?

Answer (score 0):

Now I get what you need. Below code will do what you require:

```
var WordToFind = new List<string>();
var X1Coordinate = new List<int>();
var Y1Coordinate = new List<int>();
var WordDirection = new List<string>();
while((LinesInFile = reader.ReadLine()) != null)  
{
    string[] WordsWithSpecifics = LinesInFile.Split(',');
    WordToFind.Add(WordsWithSpecifics[0]);
    X1Coordinate.Add(int.Parse(WordsWithSpecifics[1]));
    Y1Coordinate.Add(int.Parse(WordsWithSpecifics[2]));
    WordDirection.Add(WordsWithSpecifics[3]);
}
```

But I personally recommend using a class for storing structured data like this:

```
class MyDataType
{
    public string Word { get; set; }
    public int X1 { get; set; }
    public int Y1 { get; set; }
    public string Direction { get; set; }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
var myData = new List<MyDataType>()
while((LinesInFile = reader.ReadLine()) != null)  
{
    string[] WordsWithSpecifics = LinesInFile.Split(',');
    myData.Add(new MyDataType(){
        Word = WordsWithSpecifics[0],
        X1 = int.Parse(WordsWithSpecifics[1]),
        Y1 = int.Parse(WordsWithSpecifics[2]),
        Direction = WordsWithSpecifics[3]
    };
}
```

Comment: @Anna I have edited the post and completely renewed it. Hope it helps :)

Comment: That was not my problem, but I didn't explain clearly enough. Thank you, I managed to do it :)

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately we can't use classes because we didn't cover them yet :P